# Clearing AutoCompleteTextView if input option is not suggested

Tags: java, android

I am trying to allow the user to type so he gets the suggestions going, but I do not want to allow him to finish typing it in, instead I want him to select an option.

Reason for this is I need to get the ID (id is an object attribute in this case, not ID of the list element) of the selected option and if the item is not selected with a click I do not know how to do that.

I have tried using the onFocusChanged approach but it seems that the autoComplete control does not lose focus. Tried adding the following options to the parent, didn't work.

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

onFocusChange code:

```
mAutoCompleteTextView.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) -> {
        if (!hasFocus) {
            String str = mAutoCompleteTextView.getText().toString();
            CustomListAdapter listAdapter = (CustomListAdapter) mAutoCompleteTextView.getAdapter();
            for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                String temp = listAdapter.getItem(i).getName();
                if  (str.compareTo(temp) == 0) {
                        return;
                    }
                }

                mAutoCompleteTextView.setText("");
            }
    });
```

The listener never fires, even upon clicking other elements.

Comment: Sorry, not clearly understand what you want.

Comment: Basically I want the AutoComplete edit text only to be used as a filter, to "narrow down" the choices for the dropdown selections.

Comment: So why are you not use Edit text instead of AutoComplete view? Use Edit Text and add addTextChangedListener.

Comment: I need the suggestions. The user has to CLICK on one of the suggestions.